# find column which have biggest number of approved transactions sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I need to find the `Filiyal` which have biggest number of approved transactions.
I've try like this:

```
select max(Filiyal)
from Transactions
where Status = 'Approved'
```

But it gives me wrong result. Where I'm wrong?

Here is my table:

```
Filiyal  |  Status
-------------------------
 Bank1   |  Approved
 Bank2   |  Not Approved
 Bank1   |  Approved
 Bank4   |  Approved
```

Comment: Try the following one.. I've applied the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function. See the sqlfiddle.com sample here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18a92/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query as written would give you the largest value of Filiyal (alphabetically) from the set of banks that have an approved status.  If what you are looking to find is the Filiyal with the most approved records, then you need to have something that counts the records that are approved.

```
select top 1 Filiyal
from Transactions
where Status = 'Approved'
group by Filiyal
order by COUNT(Filiyal) desc
```

The group by clause returns a record for each Filiyal and the order by orders them by the number of records for each value that has 'Approved' as a status.  The "top 1" will return only the record with the most approved records.  In case of a tie though you will get one of them randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `order by desc` and `top 1`:

```
select top 1 Filiyal
     , count(*) as total_approved
from Transactions
where status = 'Approved'
group by Filiyal
order by total_approved desc
```

*P.S. Doesn't cover cases when multiple `Filiyal`s can have the same amount of maximum `total_approved`.*

Comment: @user4861279: What do you mean?